# Why is there an empty line beneath text when i send sms via python?

Tags: python, email, sms

a very basic code to send bulk email and sms to my contacts, it works fantastically. The issue is when i send sms there is a empty line underneath and it looks unprofessional. Ive tried multiple ways of messing with the "body" with no luck. I know the answer is probably so simple and im just burnt out but any help would be amazing!

```
import smtplib
from time import sleep


SenderAddress = "blahblah@gmail.com"
password = "niun2idjnwe"

e = pd.read_excel("Email.xlsx")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.ru", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(SenderAddress, password)
msg = "Hey"
subject = ""
body = "Subject:{}\n\n{}:".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
    sleep(5)

server.quit()
```

ive done a couple days of research and tried multiple different ways of changing the body with no luck. im new at python.

Comment: The extra line is after `Hey`? There's nothing in your code that's adding that, it must be happening in the email-to-SMS gateway.

Comment: i have a couple other similar codes using the same smtp and theres no text issues, but the problem with those is it fails when trying to send bulk emails.

Comment: What do you differently here than the ones that work correctly, other than getting the addresses from the spreadsheet?

Comment: Is `Hey` really the message, or did you change it for posting? Show how you're really setting `msg`, that's probably the problem. Are you getting it from a file?

Comment: theyre a bit more extensive and utilize MIMEtext and other imports to communicate with the body and other inputs. i tried to just copy/paste and connect the dots but there was always a problem.

Comment: yes i just used hey as a demo but ive tried multiple different texts and theres always an empty line underneath.

Comment: The only reason that would happen is because the text ends with newline. Use `msg.strip()` to remove any surrounding whitespace.

Comment: can you send an example? ive tried "()" after subject= and pretty much every space lol. ive tried removing things and moving things around. i end up with empty text or other random problems.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not true in the sample code you posted, your real value of `msg` must end with newlines. You can remove them with the `strip()` method.

```
body = "Subject:{}\n\n{}:".format(subject, msg.strip())
```

Comment: the result was "Hey:" and still had a empty line underneath. im so confused as to where its coming from.

Comment: I can't explain it. If you can post code that sends a message without the extra line, maybe I'll be able to see the difference.

Comment: Where exactly is that empty line? Is it before or after the `:` that you put after `msg`?

Comment: Try removing that extra `:`? Maybe it means something to the SMS gateway.

Comment: yes this is the exact code and msg. the new line begins after the : now. before i added the msg.strip() it began right after the message.

Comment: if i remove the : i get the message "Subject (newline) Hey: (newline)

Comment: I'm only talking about the `:` after `{}`, not the one after `Subject`

Comment: back to how it was originally. "hey" with an empty line beneath. i remember having a similar issue with php a long time ago and was able to fix it but im new to python

Comment: I'm back to saying I need to see some code that sends a message that doesn't have newline. If you can't see the difference, maybe I can.